# ssdt: change the types of primary key/secondary keys

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

Original table1 and Table2. Both tables has data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Table1Id] Int NULL,    

    Constraint [FK_Table1_Table2] foreign key ([Table1Id]) references [Table1] (Id)
)
```

**I'd like to change the `Table1.Id` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.**

Obviously just jump in and change the type from `int` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` for `Table1.Id` and 'Table2.Table1Id'. Then Publish. Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_ms_xx_Table1] (
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
           FROM   [dbo].[Table1])
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tmp_ms_xx_Table1] ([Id])
        SELECT   [Id]
        FROM     [dbo].[Table1]
        ORDER BY [Id] ASC;
    END
```

This code will **fail** because original `Table1.Id` is `Int` while temp table Id is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Then, I try to with Pre-Scripts. Ideally all the changes will be done manually.

```
--drop fk constraint
alter table [Table2] drop constraint [FK_Table1_Table2];

--rename table1.id
exec sp_rename 'Table1.Id', 'Id2', 'COLUMN';

alter table [Table1] add Id uniqueidentifier not null 
    default newid();

--rename table2.table1id
exec sp_rename 'Table2.Table1Id', 'Table1Id2', 'COLUMN';
alter table [Table2] add Table1Id uniqueidentifier null;


update t2 set t2.Table1ID = t1.Id
    from Table2 t2 left join Table1 t1 on t2.Table1Id2 = t1.Id2;

alter table [Table2] add constraint [FK_Table1_Table2] foreign key (Table1Id) references Table1 (Id);
```

However it **FAIL** again as SSDT is trying to compare its data structure again the target database.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 4):

You're right. The problem is that you can't include schema changes in the pre-deployment script because SSDT's deployment script is generated prior to your schema changes. It is therefore only useful for data-only changes.

The solution is to do this outside of the SSDT process altogether. Yes, it's a pre-pre-deployment script! Essentially you have to apply your change by yourself *before* you even get to the SSDT bit.

(There's probably a way to do this via a custom deployment contributor. After all, everything is possible in code...)

Can I convince you to take a look at a migration-based solution as it appears that you have sufficient need for an element of fine-grained script "customisation". [DBUp](https://dbup.github.io/) is a popular open source solution. [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll) is a more-integrated commercial solution that shares a lot with SSDT.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the old data. it will be ok without the data in table in step 2.

1.**pre-script**: copy/process old data to temp tables, delete them from original tables

```
create table #table1 (
    id int null, 
    id2 uniqueidentifier null
);
insert into #table1 (id,id2) 
    select id,newid() from Table1;

create table #table2 (
    id int null, 
    table1id int null, 
    table1id2 uniqueidentifier null
);
insert into #table2 (id, table1id) 
    select id,table1id from Table2;

update t2 set t2.table1id2=t1.id2
    from #table2 t2 left join #table1 t1 on t2.table1id = t1.id;

delete from table2;
delete from table1;
```

2. **dacpac** will auto generate the changes for schema. it will be ok because no data is existing any more.
3. **post-script**: insert data back from temp tables in pre-script:

   insert into table1 (id) 
       select id2 from #table1;

   insert into table2 (id,table1id) 
       select id, table1id2 from #table2;

Comment: have another problem when deleting the Table2 if it has reference from other tables :)

Comment: I would say the best thing about ssdt is not having to worry about deployment scripts but that only really works when either making lots of small changes or when you can guarantee changes have made it though to production. Looking at this and your other question it looks like because you are making drastic (I.e. Not procs or new tables/columns) then I would consider something like Ready Roll.

Comment: I put some more thoughts about this in a post (https://the.agilesql.club/blogs/Ed-Elliott/2016-09-20/Database-Deployments-Where-A-Customer-Manages-The-Database) hopefully this goes you some things to think about!